# Why I can't download the scala sbt from website http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html?

Tags: macos, scala, sbt

I use mac to download scala sbt but always get timeout or forward me to a 404 webpage on 4sync, I have no idea how and where to download sbt now? Does any one met the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also download from bintray,but there's no newest versions.

Try the following url: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/